# Using Facebook SDK in Android application

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am trying to let the user post to his Facebook wall. For that, I have downloaded the Facebook SDK for Android and copied the official code from Facebook to call the request method. The problem is that my SDK states that the .request method has been deprecated. I found that there are several SDKs around and I cannot find a whole set (SDK + sample code) that work for me. Can someone point to a full working set of instructions on where the get all of these?

Thanks,
  Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have make a simple program that you have to login and then you can post status to your wall. with or without dialog box.
android project [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgl4u6beu7hj5pj/androidfacebook.zip)

facebook APi [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxr10hgkg8x5d2c/com_facebook_android.rar)

First you have to create an project with sample source ( com_facebook_android) and then import it in you android project. and it will work

Cheers